# How to fade out and destroy audio on load

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, audio

I have got a basic script that allows the music to continue playing from scene 2 until scene 6, but I have been trying most of the day to get it where the audio starts to fade out and then is destroyed on scene 6, before loading into scene 7.

I have searched on here, google , youtube and even the Unity forums, but nothing works as all i am getting in my search is how to make the music continue

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Music : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    public GameObject theManager;
    public AudioSource music;
    public string loadLevel;
    public float fadeOutTime = 3f;
    bool fading;
    float fadePerSec;

    void Awake()
    {

        DontDestroyOnLoad(theManager);
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (fading)
        {
            music.volume = Mathf.MoveTowards(
            music.volume, 0, fadePerSec * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        if ((scene.buildIndex != 2) && (scene.buildIndex != 3) && (scene.buildIndex != 4) && (scene.buildIndex != 5) && (scene.buildIndex != 6))
        {
            fading = true;
            fadePerSec = music.volume / fadeOutTime;
            Destroy(theManager, fadeOutTime);
        }

    }
}
```

Here are 2 screenshots of my project

Project layout

[image]

Inspector of ScriptManager

[image]

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: `if ((scene.buildIndex != 2) && (scene.buildIndex != 3) && (scene.buildIndex != 4) && (scene.buildIndex != 5) && (scene.buildIndex != 6))` I don't know your build indices ofcourse but if you say you want it to happen in Scene6 - I would expect the 0-based buildIndex to be `5`. So your check should probably rather simply read `if(scene.buildIndex == 5) { ... }` otherwise it might simply happen already in Scene2 (where I would expect the 0-based buildIndex to be `== 1`)

Comment: Also you do `DontDestroyOnLoad(theManager);` .. but do you also `DontDestroyOnLoad` this class itself ... otherwise it will be destroyed when switching the scene so ... no callback anymore?

Comment: @derHugo Removing ```DontDestroyOnLoad(theManager);``` means that the music does not continue and also nothing as changed when following your first comment. Here is a screenshot of my build index for the layout of my project https://imgur.com/WihwEn1

Comment: I didn't say remove it for the `theManager` .. but what about the script itself? The `ScriptManager` object will probably be destroyed when a scene is changed

Comment: @derHugo No the music keeps continuing through to scene 7 where as i wish the music to fade out and stop on scene 6

Answer (score 0):

1. **Main Issue: The GameObject with this script attached is detroyed**

   The `ScriptManager` GameObject having this script attached itself is **destroyed when you switch a Scene**! Therefore `OnSceneLoaded` is probably never even called at all.
2. Then I would not use the field `public GameObject theManager;` ... you already have the field `public AudioSource music;` so I would rather use `music.gameObject` whenever a `GameObject` reference is required. Just to avoid mistakes.
3. Finally I would not use the `Update` method for checking a `bool` flag constantly just for a **one-time** event. I would recommend to rather use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html):

so something like

```
public class Music : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource music;
    public string loadLevel;
    public float fadeOutTime = 3f;

    private static Music _instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(music.gameObject);

        // If necessary use a singleton pattern to make sure this exists only once
        if(_instance)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        _instance = this;

        // Also don't destroy yourself!
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        // Just to be sure before adding a callback you should always remove it
        // This is valid even if it wasn't added yet
        // but it makes sure it is only added exactly once
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    private IEnumerator FadeOutAndDestroy()
    {
        var fadePerSec = music.volume / fadeOutTime;
        while(music.volume > 0)
        {
            music.volume = Mathf.MoveTowards(music.volume, 0, fadePerSec * Time.deltaTime);
            
            // yield says: Interupt the routine here, render this frame
            // and continue from here in the next frame
            // In other words: Coroutines are like small temporary Update methods
            yield return null;
        }

        // Now the volume is 0
        Destroy(music.gameObject);

        // and since no longer needed also destroy this object
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        if (scene.buildIndex != 7) return;
        
        StartCoroutine(FadeOutAndDestroy());
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah I got it and Thank you :)